# Cloud Endpoint API Client Library doesn't contain JAR file

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, client-library

I've just followed exactly what was said in [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/endpoints_tool) tutorial and ran the command

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle helloworld_api.NewsApi
```

I know my `NewsApi` service works, I've tested it on the Google APIs explorer.

I get a success message: `API client library written to ./getNews-v1.zip`

I extracted the zip and found the following files inside the folder (`getNews`):

[image]

No JAR file exists!! What do I use to set up the library in my Android client?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The library is included in the the android client using this line

    "compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')"

in build.gradle(app)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I point to the zip so the Android client understands the API? Could you give a more concrete example? Is this tutorial wrong then: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android

Comment: sorry...I am actually talking about the java google app engine module...didn't notice that it was python

Comment: That's cool. Any idea what's going wrong in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sources JAR and included dependencies to include in your project use '-bs default' or simply omit that option. Using '-bs gradle' or '-bs maven' assumes you are going to use one of those build tools to build a classes JAR yourself. The 'endpointscfg.py' of course won't compile sources to class files for you as it doesn't have knowledge of any Java environment.

More info in the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/endpoints_tool